# How many child processes can a node server spawn?

Tags: node.js

I'm doing a mathematical computation that is CPU intensive therefore I need to spawn a child-process using node.js because it may block the main even loop. It's not necessarily memory intensive but it is CPU intensive. Think for example a fibonacci number generator.

My only fear is that I might have alot of users, thousands at the same time doing this job and so that will mean that I will have thousands of processes running on my linux box because node.js spawns a new process every time child_process is run. My question is how many processes can a linux server handle?

Note: My server is a dual-core linux VM with 4gb memory. I.e., nothing fancy.
Note#2: I'm looking for a simple ballpark figure here. In the thousands? Thanks.

Comment: _Waaaay_ too broad. My netbook can run NodeJS and the answer then is "not very many". Put your code on a 24 core Haswell Xeon box and it'll serve tens of thousands, hence my close vote for this being too broad

Comment: Can you make it so it shares parts of the calculation among users instead of doing it all along for everyone ? Let's imagine that 3000 inputs look similar so an intermediate step could be stored somewhere.

Comment: Frederik, that's a fair suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: +1 to Frederic suggestion. Use message queue and as much workers as you have CPU cores on the other side on the queue. Immediate benefit: you can now easily add remote workers

Answer (score 0):

Two points...

1. If you can [cache/memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) results depending on your scenario, do so.
2. I would look into using a [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool), to limit your use of sparse resources. By wrapping your controller with a node-pool you can limit yourself to say 10 or 20 active workers at a given time. I wouldn't do more than 2x the number of physical cpus myself, though how many threads you can run really depend on the workers/system.  If all the worker processes are the same, it's more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fair enough number to say how many `child_process` can be handled, because in theory it should handle as many as possible processes.

It depends on your SLO(Service Level Objective). If you wish your application response in 100ms, you should start a load testing.

For example

Your master process:

```js
const cluster = require('cluster'); 
console.log(`master pid=${process.pid}`);
cluster.setupMaster({
  exec: __dirname+'/child-process.js' 
});
cluster.fork(); 
cluster.fork();

cluster
  .on('disconnect', (worker) => { 
    console.log('disconnect', worker.id);
  })
  .on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log('exit', worker.id, code, signal);
    // cluster.fork(); 
  })
  .on('listening', (worker, {address, port}) => {
    console.log('listening', worker.id, `${address}:${port}`);
  });
```

Your child process:

```js
import express from 'express';

const HOST = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT || '4000', 10);

console.log(`worker pid=${process.pid}`);

const app = express();
app.get('sync/:limit', (req, res) => {
  res.send(fibonacci(Number(req.params.limit)));
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Running at http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});

function fibonacci(limit: number): string {
  let prev = 1n,
    next = 0n,
    swap: bigint;

  while (limit--) {
    swap = prev;
    prev = prev + next;
    next = swap;
  }

  return next.toString();
}
```

Run your test by [autocannon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjol4qb6qzyAhXUyosBHRktDXUQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmcollina%2Fautocannon&usg=AOvVaw0N6Ad_--5xVLMiMOueNVDh)

```sh
$ autocannon -c 2 http://127.0.0.1:4000/100000
```

It will show you the latency and now **you can start calculate what is the maximize process it can be handled**.

> Node.js applications can get complex. Processes often end up with dozens, if not hundreds, of modules that make outside connections, consume memory, or read configuration. Each one of these operations can expose another weakness in an application that can cause it to crash.
> For this reason it’s better to keep the master process as simple as possible.

> Referrer [Thomas Hunter. Distributed Systems with Node.js](https://www.booktopia.com.au/distributed-systems-with-node-js-thomas-hunter-ii/ebook/9781492077244.html)

> Referrer [implements](https://github.com/evan361425/distributed-node/tree/master/src/tasks) for the book

However, there are methods to help you increase service handling ability.

1. Using load-balancer and scale up your service.
2. Cache the process or result.

Or simply limit the incoming to keep your SLO.